# Database Design: Best approach for handling hierarchical data insertion in SQL database

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I have a SQL database with hierarchical tables, including Campaign, AdGroup, and AdGroupAd, where each table references the previous one through foreign key relationships. Inserting data into these tables becomes complex as I need to ensure the correct order of insertion to maintain data integrity. I'm considering two approaches and seeking advice on the best approach:

- Insert records in the correct order: This involves manually inserting data into each table in the hierarchical order, ensuring that the required relationships are maintained. For example, I would first insert a campaign, then an ad group referencing the campaign, and finally an ad referencing the ad group.
- Use an entry table with a trigger: This approach involves creating an additional table called LoadingZone, acting as an entry point for the data. A trigger on the LoadingZone table would handle the insertion process by automatically inserting records into the respective tables in the correct order, based on the data provided.

I have provided small SQL examples for both scenarios above. I would appreciate insights into the pros and cons of each approach and guidance on the best approach considering factors such as data integrity, performance, and maintenance. Which approach is more suitable for handling hierarchical data insertion in a SQL database?

Note that the examples are simplified versions of the real data model.

###### Database:

```
CREATE TABLE Campaign (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  campaign_name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE AdGroup (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ad_group_name VARCHAR(50),
  campaign_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES Campaign(id)
);

CREATE TABLE AdGroupAd (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ad_name VARCHAR(50),
  ad_group_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (ad_group_id) REFERENCES AdGroup(id)
);
```

###### Scenario 1: Insert records in the correct order:

```
-- Insert a campaign
INSERT INTO Campaign (id, campaign_name) VALUES (1, 'International Stuff');

-- Insert an ad group for the campaign
INSERT INTO AdGroup (id, ad_group_name, campaign_id) VALUES (1, 'Regional 1', 1);

-- Insert an ad for the ad group
INSERT INTO AdGroupAd (id, ad_name, ad_group_id) VALUES (1, 'Blue', 1);
```

###### Scenario 2: Use an entry table with a trigger

```
-- Create the loading table
CREATE TABLE LoadingZone (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  campaign_name VARCHAR(50),
  ad_group_name VARCHAR(50),
  ad_name VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Create the trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_tables() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Insert into Campaign table
  INSERT INTO Campaign (id, campaign_name)
  SELECT NEW.id, NEW.campaign_name
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

  -- Insert into AdGroup table
  INSERT INTO AdGroup (id, ad_group_name, campaign_id)
  SELECT NEW.id, NEW.ad_group_name, c.id
  FROM Campaign c
  WHERE c.campaign_name = NEW.campaign_name
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

  -- Insert into AdGroupAd table
  INSERT INTO AdGroupAd (id, ad_name, ad_group_id)
  SELECT NEW.id, NEW.ad_name, ag.id
  FROM AdGroup ag
  WHERE ag.ad_group_name = NEW.ad_group_name
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create the trigger
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON LoadingZone
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_into_tables();
```

```
-- Insert data into the LoadingZone table
INSERT INTO LoadingZone (id, campaign_name, ad_group_name, ad_name)
VALUES (1, 'International Stuff', 'Regional 1', 'Blue');
```

These are my thoughts in favor of the trigger:

1. Self-documentation: The trigger-based approach self-documents the correct insertion order, making it easier to understand the relationships between the tables.
2. Fail-safe: If an insertion fails due to an error thrown in one of the child tables, the database should roll back the entire insert. Otherwise, this scenario could be more difficult to recover from.
3. Stronger data integrity: The trigger enforces the correct order of insertion, reducing the risk of data inconsistencies and ensuring stronger data integrity.

Thanks for any guidance on this topic.

Comment: Why not a stored procedure instead of trigger on an unrelated table?

Comment: Can you ever have a AdGroup without a Campaign, etc? If not, add `not null`. That solves pretty much all your concerns.

Comment: @Schwern Not exactly, unless I'm misunderstanding. If I put `not null` then it will just raise error (thereby preventing data integrity issues). But I'd like to know if there's a right way or wrong way here, best practice, or some other guidance given the many still remaining options.

Comment: @SalmanA I'm not all that familiar with databases yet, and I don't know what a stored procedure is. I take it then, maybe a stored procedure is the correct call in this case?

Comment: I would do it with a stored procedure (but opinions vary).

Comment: @MrChadMWood Referential integrity via constraints such as `foreign key` and `not null` is the right way. Make it impossible to make the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are useful, but they are also invisible, complicated, and can get in the way of doing things not envisioned by the trigger author. Adding a table just for the trigger adds even more complexity.

Instead, rely on constraints, such as `foreign key` and `not null`, to ensure [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity); make it impossible to insert invalid rows.

- Your foreign keys will prevent referencing an item which does not exist. This will catch if you try to insert in the wrong order.
- Declare all the foreign keys `not null`. This prevents inserting a row with no parent.
- Use auto-increment for primary keys to ensure you always get a unique id. This also makes it obvious you're inserting in the wrong order; you need to insert in the right order to get the foreign keys. It also avoids race conditions with other connections inserting at the same time.
- Use [`last_insert_id`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) (MySQL-specific) to get the ID of the previous auto-incremented insert.
- Use transactions to rollback all the inserts if any fail.

Other notes on your schema.

- Use bigints for primary keys. The ID is incremented every time an insert is *attempted*. 2 billion attempted inserts comes up fast.
- Don't arbitrarily limit the size of text fields. `varchar` is VARiable character size; you're not saving any space and just limiting your users.

```
CREATE TABLE Campaign (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  campaign_name VARCHAR(255) not null
);

CREATE TABLE AdGroup (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ad_group_name VARCHAR(255) not null,
  campaign_id bigint not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES Campaign(id)
);

CREATE TABLE AdGroupAd (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ad_name VARCHAR(255) not null,
  ad_group_id bigint not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (ad_group_id) REFERENCES AdGroup(id)
);
```

```
begin;

INSERT INTO Campaign (campaign_name) VALUES ('International Stuff');

-- Use `select last_insert_id()` to get the ID of the Campaign.
INSERT INTO AdGroup (ad_group_name, campaign_id) VALUES ('Regional 1', (select last_insert_id()));

-- Use `select last_insert_id()` to get the ID of the AdGroupAd.
INSERT INTO AdGroupAd (ad_name, ad_group_id) VALUES ('Blue', (select last_insert_id()));

commit;
```

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO Campaign (campaign_name) VALUES ('Buy our stuff');

INSERT INTO AdGroup (ad_group_name, campaign_id) VALUES ('Stuff sellers', (select last_insert_id()));

-- Bad insert, this will raise an error.
INSERT INTO AdGroupAd (ad_name, ad_group_id) VALUES ('Stuff', 1234567);

-- Roll back all the inserts.
ROLLBACK;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/3qKhZdEn).

Note: MySQL's transaction handling is inconsistent. ["InnoDB sometimes rolls back only the statement that failed, other times it rolls back the entire transaction."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-error-handling.html)  That's why the explicit `rollback` is necessary. Other databases will rollback the whole transaction on error automatically. MySQL is quite non-standard and will teach you bad habits, I advocate you switch to [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), especially while learning.

You can write a small program to do the inserts, or as [SalmanA suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409617/database-design-best-approach-for-handling-hierarchical-data-insertion-in-sql-d#comment134736187_76409617), a stored procedure, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a view an a INSTEAD OF TRIGGER, like this one :

```
CREATE TABLE Campaign (
  id              INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  campaign_name   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AdGroup (
  id              INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ad_group_name   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  campaign_id     INT  NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES Campaign(id)
);

CREATE TABLE AdGroupAd (
  id              INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ad_name         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  ad_group_id     INT  NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ad_group_id) REFERENCES AdGroup(id)
);
GO


CREATE VIEW V_campaign_group
AS
SELECT C.id AS campaigne_id, C.campaign_name,
       AG.id AS AdGroup_id, AG.ad_group_name,
       AGA.id AS AdGroupAd_id, AGA.ad_name
FROM   Campaign AS C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN AdGroup AS AG
          ON AG.campaign_id = C.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN AdGroupAd AS AGA
          ON AGA.ad_group_id = AG.id;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER EVT_INSERT_V_campaign_group
ON V_campaign_group
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

  INSERT INTO Campaign 
  SELECT campaign_name
  FROM   inserted;

  
  INSERT INTO AdGroup 
  SELECT ad_group_name, SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  FROM  inserted

  INSERT INTO AdGroupAd 
  SELECT ad_name, SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  FROM  inserted

GO
```

This code is specific to MS SQL Server but you will find equivalent in other RDBMS